# Regex - Matching repeating pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string which contains a repeating pattern of text followed by parentheses with an ID number.

```
The New York Yankees (12980261666)\n\nRedsox (1901659429)\nMets (NYC) 
(21135721896)\nKansas City Royals (they are 7-1) (222497247812331)\n\n
other team  (618006)\n
```

I'm struggling to write a regex that would return:

```
The New York Yankees (12980261666)

Redsox (1901659429)

Mets (NYC) (21135721896)

Kansas City Royals (they are 7-1) (222497247812331)

other team  (618006)
```

The newline character could be replaced later with a `string.replace('/n', '')`.

Comment: Your input string already has newlines in the right places.  Looks like all you need to do is replace some multiple newlines with single ones?

Comment: Thanks, @NedBatchelder. The following worked to replace the one or multiple newline characters with just one newline character: `re.sub('\\n+', '\n',`. I then used the following regular expression to create groups for every newline: `'(.*?)\\n'`

Comment: Looking at your example in the link given in the answer below, it's unclear what your input is. Does it contains the new line character or `\n`?

Answer (score 1):

use the negate character to achieve this.

String pat="([^\\n])"

Comment: This doesn't seem to work correctly. See [link](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%5B%5E%5C%5Cn%5D)&test_string=The%20New%20York%20Yankees%20(12980261666)%5Cn%5CnRedsox%20(1901659429)%5CnMets%20(NYC)%20(21135721896)%5CnKansas%20City%20Royals%20(they%20are%207-1)%20(222497247812331)%5Cn%5Cnother%20team%20%20(618006)%5Cn&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)